# Atiyah MacDonald: Proposition 3.5

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

In Atiyah-Macdonald's *Commutative Algebra*, on page 39, Proposition 3.5, it says

Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then the $S^{-1}A$-modules: $S^{-1}M$ and $S^{-1}A \otimes_{A}M$ are isomorphic.

Since $S^{-1}A$ and $M$ are $A$-modules so is $S^{-1}A\otimes_{A}M$.

My question is: how can one tell $S^{-1}A\otimes_{A} M$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module?

Is it true that if $M$ is an $A$-module and $S$ being a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$. Then is $M$ also $S^{-1}A$-module?

Comment: I think probably, an $A$-module $M$ is also an $S^{-1} A$-module if and only if for every $s \in S$, $s\cdot : M \to M$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, yes: the $A$-module structure on an abelian group $M$  is equivalent to a ring homomorphism $A \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$; then, if that hypothesis holds, $S$ maps to units, so by the universal property of localization, we get a ring homomorphism $S^{-1} A \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. This is just a particular instance of a general result:

If $A\longrightarrow B$ is a (commutative) $A$-algebra, and $M$ an $A$-module, the $A$-module $B\otimes_AM$ is in a natural way a $B$-module  through the scalar multiplication
$$\beta((b\otimes m) \overset{\text{def}}{=}(\beta b)\otimes m.$$
This $B$-module is said to be ‘obtained by extension of scalars’ from the $A$-module $M$.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but not an $(\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{ 0\})^{-1} \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Q}$ module. However, for any $A$-module $M$, the tensor product $S^{-1}M:=M\otimes_{A} S^{-1}A$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module.

Comment: Yes, I actually want to know this. How to conclude that $M\otimes_{A}S^{-1}A$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module?

Comment: $M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module by acting on the right term on the tensor product, by which I mean $\frac{a}{s}\cdot m\otimes \frac{b}{t}=m\otimes \frac{ab}{st}$. Also, I think you misquoted the Proposition: $S^{-1}A$ and $S^{-1}A\otimes A M$ are not in general isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I have corrected the mistake in the question.